# Cannot add Xcode data to database using SQLITE3

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sqlite, xcode4.6

I'm a bit new to Xcode and Sqlite3, and have followed many tutorials and spent countless hours on SO, but still am stuck on adding to a database with the simple iPhone app I'm trying to create. The app has a form with text fields that are used for text input, which I would like to save to a database.  My storyboard consists of two input fields and a button ("AddEvalFormButton").

This is what happens:

1. I make sure the Simulator is reset, then I run the app.  It crashes as soon as I press the button in the preceding screen to get the the Evaluation Form page (I'm assuming something went wrong with ViewDidLoad, but not sure).  However, console says the following: "You were able to create a DB".  (I also had a breakpoint for CreateOrOpenDB (see code below): 0x1e4df:  movl   -12(%ebp), %edx  <--this is utter nonsense to me; any ideas on how to use this info would be appreciated).
2. I close the iOS Simulator and run again, and this time, it does NOT crash on opening the Form screen.  I am able to input data into the the text fields, but the app crashes when I hit the AddEvalFormButton button.  There are no messages in the console this time.

The problem:

- app is crashing and I don't know why
- no data is saving: I check my Terminal and find that no table has been added to my database.

As far as I'm concerned (please correct me if I'm wrong), there are two directories I'm concerned with:

1) The one with my Xcode project

2) User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator

I have 4 files: EvaluationFormViewController.h, EvaluationFormViewController.m, EvalForm.h, and EvalForm.m.  They look like the following:

EvaluationFormViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import "EvalForm.h"

@interface EvaluationViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *efq1Field;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *efq2Field;

- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textfieldReturn:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addEvalFormButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

EvaluationFormViewController.m:

```
#import "EvaluationViewController.h"

@interface EvaluationViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfEvalFormQs;
    sqlite3 *evalFormDB;
    NSString *dbPathString;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGPoint originalOffset;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIView *activeField;
@end

@implementation EvaluationViewController

@synthesize efq1Field, efq2Field;


//FROM TUTORIAL Cocoa W/Love; need the following instance variables
CGFloat animatedDistance;
//FROM TUTORIAL Cocoa W/Love; need the following instance constants
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;

- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender {
    [efq1Field resignFirstResponder];
    [efq2Field resignFirstResponder];
}

//dismisses the keyboard when the return/done button is pressed for TextFields.
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
//dismisses the keyboard when the return/done button is pressed for TextViews.
- (BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


//FROM TUTORIAL: www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html

//Animate upwards when the text field is selected
//Get the rects of the text field being edited and the view that we're going to scroll. We convert everything to window coordinates, since they're not necessarily in the same coordinate space.
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect textFieldRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

    //So now we have the bounds, we need to calculate the fraction between the top and bottom of the middle section for the text field's midline:
    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator =
    midline - viewRect.origin.y
    - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator =
    (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
    * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;


    //Clamp this fraction so that the top section is all "0.0" and the bottom section is all "1.0".
    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }


    //Now take this fraction and convert it into an amount to scroll by multiplying by the keyboard height for the current screen orientation. Notice the calls to floor so that we only scroll by whole pixel amounts.
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }


    //Finally, apply the animation. Note the use of setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: — this will allow a smooth transition to new text field if the user taps on another.
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


//ANIMATE BACK AGAIN:  The return animation is far simpler since we've saved the amount to animate.
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

//SAME CODE AS ABOVE, BUT FOR TEXTVIEW
//FROM TUTORIAL: www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html

//Animate upwards when the text field is selected
//Get the rects of the text field being edited and the view that we're going to scroll. We convert everything to window coordinates, since they're not necessarily in the same coordinate space.
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGRect textFieldRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:textView.bounds fromView:textView];
    CGRect viewRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

    //So now we have the bounds, we need to calculate the fraction between the top and bottom of the middle section for the text field's midline:
    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator =
    midline - viewRect.origin.y
    - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator =
    (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
    * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;


    //Clamp this fraction so that the top section is all "0.0" and the bottom section is all "1.0".
    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }


    //Now take this fraction and convert it into an amount to scroll by multiplying by the keyboard height for the current screen orientation. Notice the calls to floor so that we only scroll by whole pixel amounts.
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }

    //Finally, apply the animation. Note the use of setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: — this will allow a smooth transition to new text field if the user taps on another.
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


//ANIMATE BACK AGAIN:  The return animation is far simpler since we've saved the amount to animate.
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


/**Keyboard dismissed when background is clicked or when return is hit**/
- (IBAction)textfieldReturn:(id)sender{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) viewWillDisappear: (BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc removeObserver:self name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [nc removeObserver:self name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"136676912132100.gif"]]];

}


//RELEVANT CODE FOR SQLITE ISSUE BELOW:
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //relating to sqlite:
    arrayOfEvalFormQs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self createOrOpenDB];

}

- (void)createOrOpenDB
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];

    dbPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"evalForm.db"];   
    char *error;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString]) {
        const char *dbPath = [dbPathString UTF8String];

        //creat db here
        if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &evalFormDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EVALFORMDB (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, EFQ1 TEXT, EFQ2 TEXT)";
            NSLog(@"You were able to create DB");
            sqlite3_exec(evalFormDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error);
            sqlite3_close(evalFormDB);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Problem with createopenDB");
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)addEvalFormButton:(id)sender {
    char *error;
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &evalFormDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *inserStmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO EVALFORM(EFQ1,EFQ2) values ('%s', '%s')",[self.efq1Field.text UTF8String], [self.efq2Field.text UTF8String]];
        NSLog(@"I am in the loop");

        const char *insert_stmt = [inserStmt UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_exec(evalFormDB, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK) {   
            NSLog(@"Answer added");

            //not really sure what this does:
            EvalForm *evalForm = [[EvalForm alloc]init];
            [evalForm setEfq1:self.efq1Field.text];
            [evalForm setEfq2:self.efq2Field.text];
            [arrayOfEvalFormQs addObject:evalForm];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Answer not added");
        }
        sqlite3_close(evalFormDB);
    }
}

@end
```

EvalForm.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface EvalForm : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *efq1;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *efq2;

@end
```

EvalForm.m:

```
#import "EvalForm.h"

@implementation EvalForm

@end
```

I've tried including as much info as possible (possibly overkill, my apologies).  Like I've mentioned, I'm still new to Xcode and SQLite, so I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something basic in my code.  Any input on why my code isn't working would be much appreciated.

Comment: I advice yo to learn and use Core Data, much more easy and efficient.

Comment: If the app is crashing, provide some detail on what message(s) you see when that happens. Also, add an "exception" breakpoint to stop execution when it's about to crash, so you can see where exactly the crash happens.

Comment: If you need to use SQLite rather than CoreData I would recommend using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), it does a lot of the hard work for you.

Comment: Yes, I was actually going to look into FMDB to see if it would make this easier.  Are there any incentives to using CoreData over FMDB?

Comment: you still having the problem...????